# How to calculate business days in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables available with me, one is the main_table with start_date and end_date and another is holiday_table where all the client holidays along with the weekends are marked.

I need to calculate all the business days from start_date to end_date, eliminating all the holidays occurring in the holiday_table for that particular duration.

main_table(start_date date, end_date date) and holiday_table(holidays date) 
I have a piece of code which easily separates all the holidays listed in holiday_table, only if the value of the start_date and end_date is hard-coded. 
code : 
select (to_date( '10/10/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')- to_date( '10/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) - (select count(*) from holiday_2016 t where t.holidays > to_date( '10/01/2017',

'mm/dd/yyyy') and t.holidays <= to_date( '10/10/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') ) from dual

But this is not what I want, since I have a table where there are different values for start_date and end_date, thus, these values cannot be hard-coded.

```
i/p tables : 
1. main_table
start_date  end_date
--------------------
10/01/2017  10/10/2017 
10/05/2017  10/20/2017
09/29/2017  10/05/2017

holiday_table
holidays
------------
10/01/2017 --Sunday 
10/02/2017 --Gandhi Jayanti 
10/07/2017 --Saturday 
10/08/2017 --Sunday 
10/14/2017 --Saturday 
10/15/2017 --Sunday 
10/19/2017 --Diwali

o/p table should be like :
start_date  end_date    bus_days
------------------------------------------
10/01/2017  10/10/2017    06 
10/05/2017  10/20/2017    10
09/29/2017  10/05/2017    04
```

++If this works out, I need to add filter to start_date and end_date:

1. Requests having start_date < '10/01/2017' and start_date >
   '10/20/2017' will be eliminated
2. Requests having end_date < '10/01/2017' and start_date >
   '10/20/2017' will also be eliminated

Comment: please provide sample data and an expected result (based on the data you provide)

Comment: your data model is unclear. what is content of the holidays attribute? the output is not clear as well.

Comment: I have sampled out the i/p and expected o/p tables along with the attributes of the table mentioned. Let me know if it still stands unclear.

Comment: learn how to format the data or code, it just requires a 4 char indent. There is a button `{}` in the toolbar to help you do this too.

Comment: The answer provided at the "duplicate" is a function. The solution proposed here is not.

Answer (score 0):

This approach has worked for me in the past for similar needs

```
select
      t.START_DATE
    , t.END_DATE

    ,  trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE)) + 1
     - trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE) / 7) * 2
     - (CASE WHEN to_char(t.START_DATE,'day') = 'sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     - (CASE WHEN to_char(t.END_DATE,'day') = 'saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     weekdays

    ,  trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE)) + 1
     - trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE) / 7) * 2
     - (select count(*) from holiday_table 
        where holidays between t.START_DATE and t.END_DATE)
     businessdays_A

    ,  trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE)) + 1
     - trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE) / 7) * 2
     - (CASE WHEN to_char(t.START_DATE,'day') = 'sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     - (CASE WHEN to_char(t.END_DATE,'day') = 'saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     - (select count(*) from holiday_table 
        where holidays between t.START_DATE and t.END_DATE)
     businessdays_B

from main_table T
```

**EDIT** now I have seen some sample data I'm not sure if you need to remove weekends or not. It appears you may be explicitly store ever non-working day in the holiday table so you might just need this:

```
    ,  trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE)) + 1
     - (select count(*) from holiday_table 
        where holidays between t.START_DATE and t.END_DATE)
     businessdays_C
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32f1d/6)

```
CREATE TABLE MAIN_TABLE
    (START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO main_table (START_DATE, END_DATE)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('01-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), TO_DATE('10-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'))
    INTO main_table (START_DATE, END_DATE)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('05-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), TO_DATE('20-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'))
    INTO main_table (START_DATE, END_DATE)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('29-Sep-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), TO_DATE('05-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'))
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE HOLIDAY_TABLE
    (HOLIDAYS DATE, NAME varchar2(14))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO holiday_table (HOLIDAYS, NAME)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('01-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Sunday')
    INTO holiday_table (HOLIDAYS, NAME)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('02-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Gandhi Jayanti')
    INTO holiday_table (HOLIDAYS, NAME)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('07-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Saturday')
    INTO holiday_table (HOLIDAYS, NAME)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('08-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Sunday')
    INTO holiday_table (HOLIDAYS, NAME)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('14-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Saturday')
    INTO holiday_table (HOLIDAYS, NAME)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('15-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Sunday')
    INTO holiday_table (HOLIDAYS, NAME)
         VALUES (TO_DATE('19-Oct-2017','dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Diwali')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      t.START_DATE
    , t.END_DATE

    ,  trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE)) + 1
     - trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE) / 7) * 2
     - (CASE WHEN to_char(t.START_DATE,'day') = 'sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     - (CASE WHEN to_char(t.END_DATE,'day') = 'saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     weekdays

    ,  trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE)) + 1
     - trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE) / 7) * 2
     - (select count(*) from holiday_table 
        where holidays between t.START_DATE and t.END_DATE)
     businessdays_A

    ,  trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE)) + 1
     - trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE) / 7) * 2
     - (CASE WHEN to_char(t.START_DATE,'day') = 'sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     - (CASE WHEN to_char(t.END_DATE,'day') = 'saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     - (select count(*) from holiday_table 
        where holidays between t.START_DATE and t.END_DATE)
     businessdays_B

        ,  trunc(to_number(t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE)) + 1
         - (select count(*) from holiday_table 
            where holidays between t.START_DATE and t.END_DATE)
         businessdays_C

from main_table T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32f1d/6/0)**:

```
|           START_DATE |             END_DATE | WEEKDAYS | BUSINESSDAYS_A | BUSINESSDAYS_B | BUSINESSDAYS_C |
|----------------------|----------------------|----------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
| 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-10T00:00:00Z |        8 |              4 |              4 |              6 |
| 2017-10-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-20T00:00:00Z |       12 |              7 |              7 |             11 |
| 2017-09-29T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-05T00:00:00Z |        7 |              5 |              5 |              5 |
```

Comment: The code is working absolutely fine with some necessary changes. Thanks!!

Comment: `to_char(t.START_DATE,'day') = 'sunday'` should be better written as `to_char(t.START_DATE,'fmday', 'nls_date_language = american') = 'sunday'`. I wonder why `to_char(t.START_DATE,'day') = 'sunday'` seems to work without `fm` (resp. `'sunday   '`)